# Mmenu.js integration with Angular framework

Tags: angular, mmenu

I'm trying to integrate mmenu.js in my angular project. I faced some issues while integration to the angular. so have decided to create standalone demo in angular with mmenu, but still, it is not working for me.

here is the stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sacb86

Can someone point out what went wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems there is no support for angular. The wrapper you described is for angularJS not for angular https://mmenujs.com/docs/wrappers/angular.html

Comment: I can confirm that mmenu js main version is not working with the latest version of angular, but mmenu light is working properly. https://mmenujs.com/mmenu-light/